# AJAX Http POST : No transport error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, webmethod

This is my webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

And this is the AJAX code in html page:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
                var btn_startOp = document.getElementById("startOpp");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{}",  
                    dataType: "xml",
                    url: "http://localhost:61457/WebSite1/Service.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    success: function(msg){ alert(msg.d); },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                          }
                });
```

This is giving me an error : On,

- IE Browser : No Transport
- Mozilla : Unknown

Webservice is working fine when tested on browser.

UPDATE:
This is the line in head tag in Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me with this?
This is the very first code for me..I searched a lot still its a mystery for me ... :) :(

Comment: no status code on your ajax call? like 404 or something?

Comment: No, I have changed the code given by Jai but still On IE error is: "Unknown" and on Mozilla:null(nothing displayed...)

Comment: `contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",` says you are sending XML. `data: "{}",` That is not XML.

Comment: Did you monitor your AjAX call in your browser console? like in Firebug?

Comment: I tried to monitor AJAX in IE default debugger but I really couldn't get much about what it is doing...

Comment: as @Quentin says data you are posting is not XML but an empty object,try running it after removing the `contentType` param.. monitor the call in mozilla firebug & it should tell you something like error or response status etc.

Comment: Ok ...I will check as suggested and get back here... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/WebSite1/Service.asmx/HelloWorld",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

---

1. You are returning a string value from webmethod so `dataType:"xml"` isn't required.
2. *Webservice is working fine when tested on browser.*, It means you need to have a `GET` request.

Comment: You can update the url too. but datatype json isn't required.

Comment: when URL updated it has given an error: 'Access to restricted URI denied'

Comment: I used given code not it is giving error on IE: 'Unknown' and on Mozilla:null(nothing displayed actually)

Comment: Above code is working fine. One additional thing is, I added proxy authentication code, Now it is working properly.